# Addressing table with a variable string

Tags: lua

Lang file:

```lua
local lang = {
    keys = {
        mec_boss = {
            title = "mec_boss",
            perm = "mec.perm",
        },
        police_boss = {
            title = "police_boss",
            perm = "police.perm",
        }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to get the value like this:

```lua
local test = "mec_boss"
print(lang.keys.(test).perm)
```

I have also tried `[` instead of `(`

I'm so bad at describing this. I'm so sorry!

Comment: `print(lang.keys[test].perm)` Output: `mec.perm` Use brackets to index with variables or literal strings. Don't use a dot between the table being indexed, key, and the index, [test]. Use the dot afterwards for indexing by key name (.perm).

Comment: doing a Lua tutorial and reading the reference manual would help solve such problems. guessing the right syntax usually is a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION `print(lang.keys[test].perm)`